# Why does CPU usage shoots up drastically during installation of rust packages with the cargo package manager?

Tags: software-installation, package-management

My laptop has a 4 core i5 8250u processor with 8 GB RAM. I have Pop OS installed. The CPU usage on my machine catapults to about 100% whenever I install a rust package with the cargo package manager. For example,the fans inside my laptop went full throttle today during the 'compiling' stage of the installation process of the rust package called 'procs'. I checked the cpu usage in 'htop' as well as 'bpytop' and both apps showed the cpu-usage bump. Is this something inherent with the cargo install mechanism? If yes, why is it so?

Answer (score 1):

A package manager like apt just downloads the already-compiled binaries and puts them in place. Cargo downloads the *source code* and then *compiles* it — and not just the program you're installing, but all the libraries it depends on. It's the compilation that requires a lot of system resources. The more libraries what you're installing uses, the more it has to do, the longer this takes.

If the programs you are installing are available in another way (e.g., a deb package you can install with apt), you can install them that way. I think cargo is mainly meant to be used by rust developers, with some exceptions.